Send email with large attachments
My project using Microsoft.Graph 5.15 version send an email with large attachment. I searched the web and find the below code. However there are some issues:
1.MessageItemRequestBuilder.Send cannot be use like a method
2.AttachmentsItemRequestBuilder.CreateUploadSession cannot be use like a method
There are my code snippet
   var savedDraft = await _graphClient.Users[userId].Messages.PostAsync(draftMessage);

    // Handle large attachments
   foreach (var largeAttachment in largeAttachments)
   {
      var fileStream = File.OpenRead(largeAttachment.FullName);
     var uploadSession = await _thisGraphClient.Users[userId]
         .Messages[savedDraft.Id]
         .Attachments
         .CreateUploadSession(new AttachmentItem
         {
             AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
             Name = largeAttachment.Name,
             Size = fileStream.Length,
             ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
         })
         .Request()
         .PostAsync();

     int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024; // 320 KB - Change this to fit your needs
     var fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment>(uploadSession, fileStream, maxSliceSize);

     var totalLength = fileStream.Length;
     IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {prog} bytes of {totalLength} bytes");
     });

     try
     {
         var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);
         Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ? "Upload complete" : "Upload failed");
     }
     catch (ServiceException ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
     }
 }

 // Send the draft
   await _thisGraphClient.Users[userId].Messages[savedDraft.Id].Send().Request().PostAsync();

Would someone tell me what should fix it. Thanks.

Just don't. Send emails that contain share links.

"I searched the web and find the below code." Is what you found current? And if you get errors about methods working differently have you looked up the documentation of those messages to understand why and tried to adapt? It feels like you didn't even try to jump over the lowest of bars.

@Ralf I searched the web for the error  and tried to difference method but cannot find solve the issue, so I posted here.

Are you really using 5.15? The snippet is for SDK v4 (Request() method doesn't exist in SDK v5)
